# OnClick event is not starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-button

I've created a button in my xml layout and followed with an onClick event to handle the button to start a new activity. For some reason when I click the button the app crashes. Any ideas why?

I've used this approach to creating new activities with buttons before with success. I'm Unsure why this is not working.

```
private Button view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stretchHow);
    view = (Button)findViewById(R.id.perfect);
    view.setOnClickListener(phase);
}

View.OnClickListener phase = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(view.getId() == ((Button)v).getId()){
        Intent i = new Intent(Stretch.this, Perform.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};
```

This is the error I get.

```
09-28 23:28:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 23:28:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.proj.fitness/org.proj.fitness.Perform}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060073 type #0x12 is not valid
09-28 23:28:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-28 23:28:37.364: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
```

Comment: Interesting. Please post the full logcat. Also what does the `Perform` Activity look like?

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that the error has nothing to do with the click action, but rather originates in your `Perform` activity. To be more precise: it looks like you're mixing up ids. For example, you may be supplying a layout id where a view id is expected, or vice versa, or a drawable, or string etc.

Comment: I actually got it to work. I defined my Perform.class with wrong identifier. I set the contentView with an Id not layout.

Comment: Thankyou @MH. It was my perform activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the intent is getting the wrong context since Stretch.this shouldn't be contained inside the onClickListener. You can try moving it out to another function called startPerform in your activity so it would look like so:

```
View.OnClickListener phase = new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(view.getId() == ((Button)v).getId()){
    Intent i = new Intent(Stretch.this, Perform.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }

}
};

public void startPreform () 
{
     startActivity(new Intent(this, Perform.class));
}
```

Comment: `Stretch.this` is valid and I assume the problem is in the `Perform` activity not the onClick itself...

Comment: @user1588307 you should answer your own question if you managed to solve it by yourself, not accept an answer that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Max Rasguido. I tried to answer my question but it wouldn't allow me.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the R file from the gen Eclipse folder. It will then be regenerated and the problem hopefully resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key line of your error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060073 type #0x12 is not valid
```

It is possible the event is firing but that the target is not there, or where the handler expects it to be. Do keep checking your methods, but also make sure you do not have a legitimate "not found" situation.